# Exceptions not rendering in Laravel 7 (timing out instead)

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-7

Recently, exceptions have stopped rendering in my local Laravel application. The errors are being logged fine but it is not showing on the page as it was before. If there is an issue in the code, the page just tries to load until the maximum execution time is exceeded.

It can be for very simple things. If I try to echo a variable that doesn't exist, if I try to echo like invoice->issued_by->first_name when the invoice's issued_by_id column is null... it won't work. It logs 'undefined variable' or 'trying to get property first_name of non-object' or whatever error just fine. But it won't render them. As soon as I fix the issue, the page loads perfectly fine straight away. However, the rendering of the exceptions obviously helps to resolve issues, and having to go check the logs every time the page seems slow to load is tedious.

My only guess is that something is causing the actual rendering of the error to take too long to process and that's why its timing out. But I don't know what it could be. I have put a work around in the render function of my Handler.php file to dump and die the $exception. For now, that's giving me the information I want but I'd like to try and fix the underlying issue.

**Edit:** APP_DEBUG=true in my .env file already. Sorry I forgot to mention this.

**Edit 2 (8-Sept-2020):** I've tried tracing the problem through the exception handler, and this is where I got to:

In **`Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php`**:
within the renderExceptionContent() function, I believe there may be an issue returning `$this->renderExceptionWithWhoops($e)`. If I force it to return `$this->renderExceptionWithSymfony($e, config('app.debug'))` that appears to work okay.

So I followed this over to **`Whoops\Run.php`**:
within the handleException() function, during the `foreach (array_reverse($this->handlerStack) as $handler)` loop I can dd() BEFORE `$handlerResponse = $handler->handle($exception)`, but not after.

**Edit 3 (11-Sept-2020):**
It's the ErrorPageHandler thats being run, so I opened that up followed that through as far as I could.

**`ErrorPageHandler.php`** handle() function tries to create `$report = $this->flareClient->createReport($throwable);`. It doesn't manage to complete this before it throws an exception for Maximum execution time exceeded and starts the process again.

Jump over to **`Flare.php`** where createReport() tries to `return $this->applyMiddlewareToReport($report);`. In applyMiddlewareToReport() it is failing during `$report = (new Pipeline($this->container))->send($report)->through($this->middleware)->then(function ($report) { return $report; });` it is failing (seemingly at *then()*);

Across to **`Pipeline.php`** and the then() function, through to prepareDestination(). There's a try for `return $destination($passable);` but it throws an exception and moves to the catch block.

**Configuration of my config/logging.php file:**

```
'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),


'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
    ],

    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 14,
    ],

    'slack' => [
        'driver' => 'slack',
        'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
        'username' => 'Laravel Log',
        'emoji' => ':boom:',
        'level' => 'critical',
    ],

    'papertrail' => [
        'driver'  => 'monolog',
        'level' => 'debug',
        'handler' => SyslogUdpHandler::class,
        'handler_with' => [
            'host' => env('PAPERTRAIL_URL'),
            'port' => env('PAPERTRAIL_PORT'),
        ],
    ],

    'stderr' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
        'with' => [
            'stream' => 'php://stderr',
        ],
    ],

    'syslog' => [
        'driver' => 'syslog',
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'errorlog' => [
        'driver' => 'errorlog',
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Probably not the proper answer, but, do you have debugging turned on? However, even if it's set to false, it shouldnt produce the behaviour you described..

Comment: maybe some of your code not returning value, makes it stuck

Comment: @user3532758 sorry, yes APP_DEBUG=true in my .env file.

Comment: Couldnt think of anything without knowing your setup/configuration. Perhaps a third-party package has compatibility issue..? Not sure though.

Comment: Have you tried clearing you view cache?
Have you added any packages since the error pages were last working?

If your dump and die in the Handler is working it must be something in the process of rendering the error views. Do you have any custom error pages in `resources/views/errors`?

Comment: @JonWhite I've just tried clearing the view cache and no luck. The only custom error page I have is a 403.

I haven't added any new packages recently. The biggest change I've made is that I've started to implement Policies into my application. However, I am fairly confident that this issue is more recent than the policies implementation, and I wouldn't think they'd be disrupting the error rendering would they?

Comment: @JamesV That's interesting, does the 403 with the custom error page successfully render?
I think from here you're going to have to follow the execution path of the exception handler and dump out along the way to identify where the point of failure is.
You know your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class is being called and successfully executing `report`. Now you'll need to dig into the `render` function and see where the code gets to before timing out.

Comment: @JonWhite yes, the 403 seems to work fine.

I've tried tracing the issue through the exception handler like you've suggested. I've edited the question to include details about this. I'm not super knowledgeable about what I'm doing so I've hit a wall and I'm not really sure how to keep tracing this issue further.

Comment: @JamesV that's interesting that your custom 403 renders...
From your original post I don't think you've tried to implement anything other than Laravel's default handler right?
I would suggest deleting your vendor folder and running composer update to rewrite your dependencies.
You could check which handlers are being run by commenting out all the code in the foreach loop and doing `dump($handler)` with a `die` at the end of the loop. What do you have configured in your `config/logging.php` file?

Comment: @JonWhite Removed the vendor folder and ran composer update but no luck.

I've updated the original post again with more detail upon being able to identify the handler as ErrorPageHandler, including my config/logging.php file.

Comment: I have to say I'm stumped mate!
I guess you can break down the chain of calls in `Flare.php` in the `applyMiddlewareToReport()` function and try to see what's being passed to `$report` in the callback inside the call to `then()` but if that's something weird there'd be a whole new debugging process to try to identify what's wrong there... You could potentially work around this by creating custom error pages for every possible error but that's not exactly a complete solution.

Comment: That's okay. I appreciate the assistance in any case so thank you. If nothing else, I learnt a little more about how things are working under the hood.
I noticed that Laravel 8 is up so perhaps I'll update and see if that resolves the issue. It'll probably do little to explain the root cause though.